# Reputation decreased by more than 2600 points. How I can find the reason for this?

Tags: bug, reputation

I have been a Stack Overflow volunteer for more than 9 years and over the years I have built up a reputation of almost 10,000.

Suddenly my reputation decreased by 2600+ for no apparent reason. How can I find out the reason for this?

Comment: The usual reason for a drop like that is a large voting ring that was voting on your content to help obscure their illegal voting pattern was found and nuked.

Comment: No (private) updates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3399356/slava-rozhnev?tab=reputation)?

Comment: Now reputation jump 6.681 to 8,806 in is definitely bug

Comment: Looks like the cleaners are still at work. You seem to have gotten about 2000 of that rep back

Comment: And the usual cause is is not the true cause. Truly these are unusual times.

Answer (score 21):

It's not a bug. There were some spam flags raised against your account by staff. After discussion, moderators reversed the spam flags and took a different path so you got most of the rep back (not all, as we did remove some posts).

You have a message in your inbox related to this. Apologies for the confusion on the rep.

Comment: Is there anything other users should be aware of to avoid this situation? (if you can share it without compromising this user's privacy)

Comment: @tgdavies [Don't spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)